# I need to use a bitmap image but i dont know how

Tags: android

Im trying to change the google maps marker in a Android application, I tried this way:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(player).title("player").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)));
```

but it says that I have to use a bitmap image, what should I do?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.crosilla.mappeprova2, PID: 18930 
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap
```

Comment: can you add the error?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.example.crosilla.mappeprova2, PID: 18930                                                                com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok. Try with a resource from the mipmap folder.

Answer (score -1):

```
call this on button click:
       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
then :
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(PhotoUpload.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait......");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SavedPhoto", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            Bitmap photo = null;
            try {
                photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

                 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage , Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                CircularImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.profileimage);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);

        }
    }
```